# django pdf image generation

Tags: django, pdf

I am migrating a site from php to Django (a framework I am still learning). In the php version I was using ImageMagick to pull the first page (the cover) of a pdf file and display it as an img. I have done a little searching and not turned up anything similar with Django. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this could be accomplished?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick has Python bindings I think. http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/